# Bleed port diameter on Magura HS 11 rim brakes?

Tags: rim-brake, magura

Although the bike is barely six months old and the brake pads are very far from worn, I find the HS11 brakes a bit soft/spongy: I like the brakes to work with a short run.

[Tightening the adjustment bolt](https://newwheel.net/questions/display/PKB/Adjusting+Magura+HS-11+Hydraulic+Rim+Brake+Pads) didn't make much of a difference.

Magura suggests bleeding the system, but I'd first like to try and *burp it*, like I do on my other bike, with Shimano hydraulic disk brakes, with great success.

But to buy the right oil funnel, I need to know the diameter of the bleed port on the lever.

Does someone know?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

---

Edit: Starting at 1m33s, [this video from Magura](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ3GMv11OKA) show how to insert a syringe at the lever.

For just a filling/burping, it should first be filled with mineral oil before pulling the lever, hitting the cable + brake cylinder, putting the lever at the horizontal level and then at a -45° angle as a way to get rid of air bubbles.

Comment: I'd take a bike that new to the dealer! Not to void the warranty.

Comment: In the absolute, I agree, but they are currently super busy because of the covid19 epidemic. Besides, burping is just a five minute job, and Magura uses mineral oil like Shimano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threaded ports on Magura brakes I have worked on are bigger in diameter than Shimano, so the bucket tool in your picture would not fit, don't waste money on one uneccesarily, though you can get kits like that to suit a whole range of different brakes.

However, Magura have a feature called "Easy Bleed Technology" where you only need to put a syringe (minus plunger) into the lever bleed port. There are manuals and other guidance on the website https://www.magura.com/en/components/techcenter/?p=2633  (also https://www.magura.com/media/1742/hs11_hs33_2014_en_06.pdf though you note this is an old version).

This would allow you to do a simple burp of the lever with just a syringe, though I would use original Magura brake fluid to maintain the warranty ("Application.of.not-original.MAGURA.parts.and.lubrication.products" would void the warranty, as will "Incorrect Maintenance").

Note that in my experience, Magura brakes, especially entry level, have an amount of flex and therefore modulation. This can be good for many users, however it can feel spongy if you are used to a stiffer feel. So if once you have burped the brakes, the brakes stop the wheels well but have plenty of modulation, it may not be due to air in the lines. Just bear that in mind.

It sounds like something you're comfortable doing it but if you have any doubts, no harm in waiting for the bike shop.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The HS11 changed a bit over time, and the latest PDF is here :

"WORKSHOP MANUAL HS 2017 EN
" https://www.magura.com/en/components/techcenter/?p=2633

It doesn't explain how to fill with an oil funnel (just how to bleed with two syringes).

I'll try with a syringe + the mineral oil I use for the Shimano I have handy and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, I included that link